# Using custom commands in Multicraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-java-edition-server

I'm trying out using Multicraft to manage some aspects of my public server. There's a command option that is supposed to allow commands to be run by the web app when players type the commands into chat. It would be a usuful way of allowing staff to do certain things without giving them op privileges.

Right now using teams/triggers they have the ability to go into and out of spectator mode, but I wanted to give them the ability to teleport to players (in spectator) to check on them. ie. When they log on for the first time, they sometimes come in hacking and breaking things...

The settings in the control panel for this is:

```
Name:          Teleport Other
Required Role: [Administrator]
Prerequisite:  
Chat:
Response:
Run:           builtin:tp_other
```

This is one of the built in ones, but I can't seem to get it to work (I set myself as an Admin). Does anybody know the appropriate settings to use here and the right thing to type into chat to get it to work?

Comment: It is a vanilla server. It's using rcon to send console commands to the server (a built in vanilla feature of minecraft) and is listening to the log files (created by vanilla minecraft). Multicraft is a wrapper, not a mod.

Comment: @scriptHero Correct me if I'm wrong, but that only applied to technical mod support right?

Comment: I don't have enough info to make a full answer, but I'm fairly certain this is what the PEX plugin was designed for.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to type something into chat to get this to work on the line designated "Chat:" you will want to add a chat command there for example, "tpother". Otherwise you can only use the command from the console.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using a skript menu hooked up to a trigger with a skript like command? `command /spectate:
Events here`